# /usr/bin/ld file missing in snow leopard

Tags: compilation, fortran

I am trying to compile a fortran program using gfortran installed on Mac OSX, and I get the following error:

```
collect2: cannot find 'ld'
```

And when I try

```
ls -l /usr/bin/ld
```

I get

```
ls: /usr/bin/ld: No such file or directory
```

Can someone tell me how I can install this file?

Answer (score 0):

ld comes with XCode Tools, which you need to install separately from XCode:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ld.1.html